# How to set Proxy Auto Config (PAC) file in sdcard of Android

Tags: android, proxy, pac

Excuse me?
I pushed the file  'proxy.pac' to sdcard using this command:

```
 adb push C:\Users\zuokang.li\Documents\proxy.pac /sdcard/
```

I try to set proxy auto config in android. So I set pac url "file:///sdcard/proxy.pac".But it cannot work.

I don't know whether it is set right. Can you help me ? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: have you found anything related to this

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Android doesn’t accept setting a local PAC file (127.0.0.1 doesn't seem to work either) and may even cause browser crashes for an invalid proxy port (-1). Therefore either

- Use http://some_host/proxy.pac and store the file on some host, or
- Use Firefox for Android and the exact same settings you used above (verified) - see https://www.topbug.net/blog/2015/03/02/configure-proxy-using-pac-files-on-firefox-for-android/ for info.

Comment: Excuse me. Can the proxy work on others app, like google play when using firefox PAC setting

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue with my android phone, and searching for a solution I noted that the only one is to access to a web server for getting the `.pac` file (as Roy explains). But I wanted the solution (all about this) locally in my phone.

I installed a thin web server in my phone called [SimpleHttpServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ubi.common.http.server) from Google Play and proceed as you do to set the `.pac` file using the URL provided by the web server (previously, I created a directory, located the `.pac` file inside it and pointed the web server root folder to that directory).

Additionally, I installed [Simple Text Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxistar.textpad) for `.pac` file edition and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For use a PAC file in Android you can use Drony, looks ugly, but works! Even if you need authentication.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy.drony

Answer (score 0):

Since `file:///` is disabled on Android, you can convert the pac file to base64 and use this format:

```
data:application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig;base64,
```