# Setting global Proxy PAC on Android

Tags: android, proxy, adb, android-networking, android-internet

I'm looking to set a global Proxy Pac URL on Android.

I tried with `adb shell settings put global proxy_pac_url` however it seems Android does not handle this, even though it seems to be specified: http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java#3234

Setting `global http_proxy` does work, but the disadvantage is that the only way to unset the proxy settings is to reboot the device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Proxy Auto Config (PAC) file in sdcard of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691220/how-to-set-proxy-auto-config-pac-file-in-sdcard-of-android)